# How to get Cognito Identity Pool ID for a new user

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

After importing the AWS module I go ahead and declare the `cognitoidentityserviceprovider` variable:

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");

let AWS_REGION = "us-east-1";
let USER_POOL_ID = 'us-east-1_4RQvUuPkX';
let AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID = 'l703om838lkem323m04tiparls';
let AWS_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID = 'us-east-1:112e122-bdd5-1234-983b-0afff8de2b3f';

AWS.config.update({
  region: AWS_REGION,
});

let cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  apiVersion: "2016-04-19",
  region: AWS_REGION
});
```

After the initial configuration is set I am ready to define the `create_user` function that I can use to create a new Cognito user supplying this functions with the user's `email` and `password`:

```
async function create_user(email, password) {
  let params = {
    UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID,
    Username: email,
    DesiredDeliveryMediums: ["EMAIL"],
    TemporaryPassword: password,
    UserAttributes: [
      {
      Name: "email",
      Value: email
      },
      {
      Name: "email_verified",
      Value: "true"
      }
    ]
  };
  return await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser(params).promise();
}
```

Next, I define another function `confirm_user` which I am going to use to confirm the new user by setting the user's password:

```
async function confirm_user(sub_id, password) {
  let params = {
    Password: password, 
    UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID, 
    Username: sub_id,
    Permanent: true
  };
  return await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminSetUserPassword(params).promise();
}
```

With both `create_user` and `confirm_user` functions defined I can now create a new Cognito user and confirm it on spot without a need for the user to confirm the sign-up process:

```
async function main(email, password) {
  let user_data = await create_user(email, password);
  let sub_id = user_data.User.Attributes[0].Value;
  let confirm_data = await confirm_user(sub_id, password);
}

let EMAIL = 'foo@bar.com';
let PASSWORD = 'MY_PASSWORD';
main(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
```

Since I want to get the user's Identity Pool ID (as `identityID` variable here) I need to define a third function that I name as `authenticate_user(email, password)`:

```
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

async function authenticate_user(email, password) {

  var authenticationData = {
    Username: email,
    Password: password,
   };
  let auth_details = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

  let poolData = { 
    UserPoolId : USER_POOL_ID,
    ClientId : AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID
  };
  let pool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

  let userData = {
    Username: email,
    Pool: pool
  };
  let cognito_user = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
  let jwt_token;
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    cognito_user.authenticateUser(auth_details, {
      onSuccess: (result) => {
        jwt_token = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
        return resolve(jwt_token);
      },      
      onFailure: (err) => {
        return resolve(err.message || JSON.stringify(err) );
      },
    });
  });

  let logins = {};
  logins["cognito-idp." + AWS_REGION + ".amazonaws.com/" + USER_POOL_ID] = jwt_token;

  let creds = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: AWS_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    Logins: logins
  });

  let IdentityId;  
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    creds.get(function(err) {
      IdentityId = creds.data.IdentityId;
      resolve(IdentityId);
    });
  })
  return IdentityId;
}
```

Apparently it is a very long and complex way of getting the user's `identityID`. Is there a simpler way to get the user federated Identity Pool ID? Aside from the complexity, we need to know the user password to get the user's Identity Pool ID. Is there a way to get it without knowing the user's password?

Comment: What do you need the Identity ID for? How are you planning to use it later?

Comment: Identity ID usually doesn't change. So you can store it in your user pool as a custom attribute. If you get an error if ID has changed, get the new ID from identity pool and overwrite in your user pool.

Comment: There is number of reasons we need the user's Cognito Identity Pool Id. The question is how to get the Identity Pool ID without knowing user password.